# Get object from array by clicked button id value Javascript, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a phones array that contains data from JSON:

```
var phones = [
        {
            "age": 0,
            "id": "motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi",
            "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg",
            "name": "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
            "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\r\n\r\nExperience the future with Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).",
            "price": 150
        },
```

It displays as a ul li by this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="listTemplate">

        <ul id = "list">
            <% for (var i=0; i< phones.length; i++) { %>
            <li><%=phones[i].age %><br>
            <%=phones[i].name%><br>
            <%=phones[i].id%><br>
            <img src="<%=phones[i].imageUrl%>"/><br>
            <%=phones[i].snippet%><br>
           <p>Price: <%=phones[i].price%></p>
                <button id="<%=phones[i].id%>" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Buy</button>
            </li>
            <% } %>

    </ul>
</script>
```

This template sets button id to id of the phone. By clicking this button I want to get "id", "name" and "price" from phones array. To achieve this I wrote this code:

```
 $("#list").delegate("button",'click',function(){

   var purchase = $.grep(phones, function () {
        return this.id === phones.id;
    });

    console.log(purchase);
});
```

But problem is that it gives me all objects from phones array:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
```

Comment: What's `phones.id` here `this.id === phones.id` ? `phones` is just an array of objects that you can access its objects one-by-one using their indexes. It has no property called `id`

Answer (score 0):

Your `grep` is wrong:

- `this` in the `delegate` function gives you a reference to clicked element
- after compare to the existing `phones` array of objects
- after grep only the particular `phone` with a correct ID

.

```
 $("#list").delegate("button",'click',function(){

    var purchase = $.grep(phones, function(current){
        console.info(current); // gives you phones one by one
        return current.id===this.id; // return only clicked one
    });

    console.log(purchase); // only array of clicked items
    console.log(purchase[0]); // phone with same id
    console.log(this); // clicked item

});
```